# KnockoutJS - Selecting an option using a Javascript Object

Tags: knockout.js

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax to select an option using a JavaScript object and KnockOutJS. I've taken the example below directly from http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html, example 3.

```
<p>
    Your country: 
    <select data-bind="options: availableCountries, optionsText: 'countryName', value: selectedCountry, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
</p>

<div data-bind="visible: selectedCountry"> <!-- Appears when you select something -->
    You have chosen a country with population 
    <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry() ? selectedCountry().countryPopulation : 'unknown'"></span>.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Constructor for an object with two properties
    var Country = function(name, population) {
        this.countryName = name;
        this.countryPopulation = population;    
    };        

    var viewModel = {
        availableCountries : ko.observableArray([
            new Country("UK", 65000000),
            new Country("USA", 320000000),
            new Country("Sweden", 29000000)
        ]),
        selectedCountry : ko.observable() // Nothing selected by default
    };
</script>
```

selectedCountry has nothing selected, as noted in the remark. Let's say I want to have the USA selected by default.

I tried this:

```
selectedCountry : ko.observable([availableCountries()[1]])
```

And I tried this:

```
selectedCountry : ko.observable([new Country("USA", 320000000)])
```

I'm probably just missing something really obvious (I *am* fighting off a helluva cold)... can anyone please point out my oversight or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're running into is a limitation of declaring your view models as JavaScript object literals.  When you try :

```
selectedCountry : ko.observable([availableCountries()[1]])
```

that's equivalent to

```
selectedCountry : ko.observable([this.availableCountries()[1]])
```

and since your object literal hasn't been fully declared yet, "this" is actually pointing to the outer scope (global in this case) which has no "availableCountries" function.  If you try :

```
selectedCountry : ko.observable([viewModel.availableCountries()[1]])
```

you run into a different problem which is that viewModel is still undefined until the closing } bracket is encountered.

A better approach here is to use function declaration (or "constructor" declaration) like so:

```
var viewModel = function(){
   var self = this;
   self.availableCountries = ...
   self.selectedCountry = ko.observable(self.availableCountries()[1]);
}

var myViewModel = new viewModel();
```

This will allow all your internal references to exist at the time of construction.  It also takes care of some reference issues if your view model has any event handlers called from parent or child scopes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Both answers were correct (thanks also to Meryovi) but this is how I have my "real" data setup, and was hoping a vanilla example might help. I have opened a new question using JFiddle and something representing my real data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263079/knockoutjs-getting-an-undefined-value-not-sure-why

Comment: Thanks Todd, I'll take a look at your new question.